# JavaScript: How do I add a custom class object as a key of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, object, key

I have created a custom class with the property “name”

I also added a function to the class which returns true if 2 objects have the same name. This function works when I compare 2 custom objects with the same name.

However, I am facing problems when I added these custom class objects as keys in an array/object.

Suppose my custom class object is a. It is also a key in an array. When I compare a with the keys in the array, I get that a is not in the array.

My class constructor:

```js
class node {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  getname() {
    return this.name;
  }
  equiv(other) {
    return Boolean(this.name == other.name);
  }
  inarray(array) {
    for (let key in array) {
      if (this.name== key.name)
      {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}

var a = new node("assss");
var b = new node("bssss");
var a2 = new node("assss");

var c = {a:1, b:2}

console.log( a.equiv(a2) ) // true
//But
console.log( a.inarray(c) ) // false
```

`a.equiv(a2)` returns `true`
**But**
`a.inarray(c)` returns `false`

^ this is my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> since you have upadated your question :

just replace

```
if (this.name == key.name)
```

by

```
if (this.name == key)
```

because `key` is a string (not an object) and it' values are `'a'` or `'b'`
they are the keys of  { **a**:1, **b**:2 }

```js
class node {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  getname() {
    return this.name;
  }
  equiv(other) {
    return Boolean(this.name == other.name);
  }
  inarray(array) {
    for (let key in array) {
      if (this.name == key)
      {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}

var a  = new node("a")
  , b  = new node("b")
  , a2 = new node("a")
  , c  = { a:1, b:2 }
  ;
console.log( a.equiv(a2) ) // true
console.log( a.inarray(c) ) // true
```

Comment: It should be "this.name == key" because you want the key name, not the key value. And I believe the test he wrote is wrong, it should be "console.log(a.inarray(c))"

Comment: @ZionAy, no, in this code, the value of `key` is always `'name'` and never `'a'` or `'b'` as `this.name` could be

Comment: I agree with what you say, but your test is on another node instance (I think the OP made mistake there). If you check the OP code, you can see that "c" variable is an object with key names "a" and "b". Although I would just use "Object.keys(array).includes(this.name)" However, if it was an array of strings like ["a,", "b"] and not an object then you are correct to use array[key].

Comment: I have changed the test, made a typo oops. @Zion Ay, aren’t the keys in the array also nodes? So won’t I have to check if this.name is same as key.name? 

I’m not sure if the keys stored in the array stay as nodes

Comment: After testing more, I have realised that the keys are stored as the name of the variables. The keys are literally “a” and “b”

Comment: @RaghaRao yes, that's what I wrote in my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot mister Jojo, however when I changed the name to something else, the key is still the variable name as a string

Comment: Just to update, @MisterJojo your answer works with the small addition of                        
`node.prototype.toString = function nodetostring() {
  return this.name;     
}; `

Comment: @RaghaRao ? it is the same method with `getname()`

Comment: toStringi seems to be something more abstract, it overrides the property where objects get turned into strings when added as keys. getname() is just a way to access the name value. I came over from python so I would draw parallels with __str__.           (Just am additional info, the toString method has to be called outside the class)

Comment: Meant to say `__str__(self)` from python

Comment: @RaghaRao  you can also use getters/setters  https://coryrylan.com/blog/javascript-es6-class-syntax  ; but please stop messaging me with unnecessary guesswork